# Getting a 404 There is no Action mapped for namespace error

Tags: tomcat, struts2, struts2-namespace, action-mapping

I'm working a Struts2 Web Application. Everything was running fine. All actions are getting mapped properly and the application correctly redirects to pages. However, when I do the SAME for this particular module (related to File Upload), it just FAILS! I don't understand what's wrong, I've tried various combos of "/" and all and I still can't get the page to re-direct. What am I doing wrong?

My `struts.xml` :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!--  <!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
     -->
    <!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.1//EN" 
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.1.dtd">


<struts>
    <constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation"
        value="false" />
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="false" />
    <constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources"
        value="ApplicationResources" />

    <package name="default" extends="struts-default" namespace="">
        <action name="login" class="com.proconsulto.action.LoginAction" method="execute">
            <result name="success">/Dashboard.jsp</result>
            <result name="failure">/SignIn.jsp</result>
           </action>

           <action name="signup" class="com.proconsulto.action.UserAction" method="addUser">
            <result name="success">/Dashboard.jsp</result>
            <result name="failure">/SignIn.jsp</result>
           </action>

            <action name="logout" class="com.proconsulto.action.LoginAction" method="logout">
            <result name="success">/SignIn.jsp</result>
            </action>

           <action name="placerequest" class="com.proconsulto.action.PlaceRequestAction" method="placeRequest">
           <result name="success">/Success.jsp</result>
           </action>

    </package>
</struts>
```

And the form from where it should redirect:

```xml
<s:form theme="simple" action="placerequest.action" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
            <ul style="list-style-type:none;">
            <li class="field"><p id="qaz">Headline : <br/><s:textfield style="width:550px;align:center;display:inline;" name="headline" cssClass="text input"></s:textfield></li>
            <li class="field"><p id="qaz">Description :<br/> <s:textarea style="width:550px;display:inline;align:center;" name="description" cssClass="textarea input"></s:textarea></li>
            <li class="field"><p id="qaz">File Upload (if any) :<br/> <s:file style="height:auto;width:550px;display:inline;align:center;" name="userImage" cssClass="text input" /></li>
            <div class="medium default btn"><s:submit value="Proceed"/></div>&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <div class="medium default btn"><s:reset value="Reset"/></div>
```

`placerequest` is the action which just won't get mapped!

Please help.

Complete error message:

> type Status report
>
> message There is no Action mapped for namespace [/] and action name [placerequest] associated with context path [/ProConsulto].
>
> description The requested resource (There is no Action mapped for namespace [/] and action name [placerequest] associated with context
>   path [/ProConsulto].) is not available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a namespace to the package, like `namespace="/"`. But if you want to stick with `namespace=""` (that could create problems and/or unattended results), you can try to specify it in the form:

```xml
<s:form action="placerequest.action" namespace="" ... >
```

Also, for test purposes only, include in your project the [Struts2 Config Browser plugin](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/config-browser-plugin.html), to see how actions are mapped (browse them with the left menu).

[image]

Remember to remove it before releasing to production ;)